# Downgrade Samsung 2 7.0 from CyanogenMod 10.1 (Jelly Bean 4.2.2) to stock ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.2-jelly-bean, downgrade

I recently updated my Samsung Tab 2 7.0 (GT-P3100) to Jelly Bean 4.2.2.

But I after successfully installing, I see that there's too many things that I don't like with the update.

1. Alphabetic Indexing is not present.
2. Confusing settings (unlike previous version)
3. Hate Apollo. Music suddenly stop. Shuffle always default to OFF whenever using the player. Liked more the default samsung music player.

Is there a way to restore back previous OS version provided by Samsung? Previously, it's 4.0.4 if my memory serves me right.

I was also trying to "Restore" in Samsung Kies but the software always cannot detect my tab. Tried uninstalling/reinstalling Kies with the same outcome.

How can I go back to stock ROM?

Comment: You might want to check [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) for a ROM source. If you found the corresponding stock ROM, you can flash it via Odin/Heimdall (as for your device not being detected: try different boot modi, such as e.g. download mode, recovery, fastboot).

Answer (score 1):

It’s very important to make sure you perform a backup of all your data before attempting to install this!

Follow the steps below:

1. Make a backup of your all data.
2. Download the stock firmware for your device [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-P3100/). (Stock ROM is also on 4.2.2)
3. Download it and then unzip the file. (Do not extract the `tar.md5`)
4. Open Odin 3.04 (If you don’t have it you can download it [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/sirg77a026z67ox/Odin3-v1.85.zip))
5. Restart your device into download mode, to do this press the <kbd>Power</kbd>  and <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> button on your device.
6. Connect your phone and wait until you get a yellow/blue color with port number in Odin software interface. (If your system didn't detect the device, re-install the USB device driver/Kies)
7. Add the **firmware_name.tar.md5** to PDA, verify re-partition is NOT ticked, Start flash, don’t touch anything and wait a few minutes.
8. Your device should now reboot.

**NOTE**: **Do it on your own RISK**

Comment: The stock firmware is at 4.2.2 :)